# trying to insert an array but Cannot access offset of type string on string laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i want to insert an array but it tells me Cannot access offset of type string on string

and i made foreach and when i do $return->request
it looks like

```
{
    _token: "qb7dTYdsDVtw1RJnQQARzJMEqIfHPeQbHobiC8u2",
    _method: "POST",
    name: "Wanda Rojas",
    phone: [
    "+1 (841) 393-5088",
    "+1 (769) 441-1936"
    ],
    address: "Et est cum delectus"
}
```

and here is my model for clients

and i make phone field as array in protected $casts

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'phone' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

here is my form

```
<form action="{{route('clients.store')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('POST')
    
        <input type="text" placeholder="add name" name="name"><br>
        @for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) <div class="form-group">
            <label>@lang('site.phone')</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone[]" class="form-control">
            </div>
        @endfor
            <input type="text" placeholder="add address" name="address"><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
</form>
```

and here is my controller at store method

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return $request;

    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'phone.*' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required'
    ]);

    $phone = $request->phone;
    foreach ($phone as $p){  
        $add = new Client();
        $add->name = $request->name;
        $add->phone = $p['phone'];
        $add->address = $request->address;
        $add->save();
    };

    return redirect()->route('clients.index');
}
```

Comment: What about if you change `$add->phone = $p['phone'];` to `$add->phone = $p;`?

Comment: error htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: You cannot output arrays in blade/PHP with echo, you would need to output the phone numbers using @foreach loop or `print_r($phone, true)` inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Your code when you store client should looks like this

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //return $request;

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|array|min:1',
            'phone.*' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required'
        ]);


        $phone = $request->phone;

        $add = new Client();
        $add->name = $request->name;
        $add->phone = $phone; // $phone it's already an array, so you should only set it to property 
        $add->address = $request->address;
        $add->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('clients.index');
    }
```

and in clients.index.blade.php to access phone

```
@foreach($client->phone as $phone)
  ...
  {{ $phone }}
  ...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the array of phone numbers so `$p` is the phone number. `$add->phone = $p` should resolve your issue.